# Spawning pods dynamically at runtime from another pod

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible for a pod to act like a spawner? When someone calls the api service in the first pod, it should spawn a new pod. This seems like a very simple thing but I cant really figure out where to look in the docs. Someone already mentioned using operators but I dont really see how that would aid me.

Im currenlty migrating a project which uses docker as a spawner to create other dockers. I somehow need this principle to work in kubernetes pods.

Kind regards

Comment: You need to call [The Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/).  From within Kubernetes, the launching pod would need to have a ServiceAccount with appropriate RBAC permissions.  Many SO questions I've seen that want to do something like this would be simpler with a job queue like RabbitMQ and a long-running worker Deployment, rather than trying to use the Kubernetes API.

Comment: Do you need to spawn new pods based on some condition?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Kubespawner part of JupyterHub ?

I have been trying to find alternatives to Kubespawner and Kubernetes Operators might be the answer. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/

GL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).